# background color in cardview title (react-native)

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a cardview in react-native with a title and body. however, i want to add a background color to the tittle but not able to do it.

i was able to create the cardview with a title header but not able to add a background color that covers the entire portion of the header. 
see image attached for an example of what i want to implement.
As you can see, the card view has a tittle of summary and the title/header portion has a gray background. below the header is the body which contain the content of the cardview.  i want to implement the same in react-native.  can someone help? thanks in advance

[image]

```
//This is an example of Card View// 

import React from 'react';
//import react in our code. 

import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
//import all the components we are going to use.

import { Card } from 'react-native-elements';
//import Card

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Card title="Local Modules">
        {/*react-native-elements Card*/}
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            This is a card from the react-native-elements
          </Text>
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#34495e',
  },
});
```

Comment: What is the issue here? As you are using `container` and `paragraph` styles, add aother one for `header:{backgroundColor: /* color you want */,}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Card title={
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <Text>Local Modules</Text>
    </View>
  }
...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like this :

```
//This is an example of Card View// 

import React from 'react';
//import react in our code. 

import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
//import all the components we are going to use.

import { Card } from 'react-native-elements';
//import Card

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Card title="Local Modules">
          <View style={styles.header}>
              <Text> Summary </Text>
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            This is a card from the react-native-elements
          </Text>
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  header: {
   backgroundColor : '#C4C4C4'
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#34495e',
  },
});
```

Comment: hi Praz, this code change doesnt produce the desire result.  I am looking to implement a card view exactly as it asppears in the image (ignoring the rounded corner).  the code you provided does have a background in the header but there is space on the left and end right side.  also, the background is thin and doesnt have space top and bottom of the text summary as the image.    you added summary text to the cardview. there is already a header "local modules"